# How to pivot dataframe string value with Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have some trouble with Pivot (Seem like Pivot in excel). i tried it so many times but i have no idea. Please anyone help me.

Below is a sample data.

```
Date report     Result
01/11/2020      Achieved
01/11/2020      Achieved
02/11/2020      Failed
02/11/2020      Failed
02/11/2020      Achieved
03/11/2020      Achieved
```

Then result that i need to make it as below

```
Date report      Result
01/11/2020       100.00%
02/11/2020       33.33%
03/11/2020       100.00%
```

Remark : The percentage result comes from Countif('Date report' and 'Achieved')/Countif('Date report')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare values by `Achieved` with  [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), aggregate `mean`, multiple `100` and convert to percentages:

```
df1 = (df['Result'].eq('Achieved')
                   .groupby(df['Date report'])
                   .mean()
                   .mul(100)
                   .round(2)
                   .astype(str)
                   .add('%')
                   .reset_index())
print (df1)
  Date report  Result
0  01/11/2020  100.0%
1  02/11/2020  33.33%
2  03/11/2020  100.0%
```

Another idea, thank you @Chester:

```
df1 = (df['Result'].eq('Achieved')
                   .groupby(df['Date report'])
                   .mean()
                   .map('{:.2%}'.format)
                   .reset_index())
print (df1)
```

- `'{:.num%}'` where `num` is precision after the decimal point, read about [`mini string language`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: Similar idea, `df['Result'].eq('Achieved').groupby(df['Date report']).mean().map('{:.2%}'.format)` but leveraging on mini string language

Comment: Added few dets, feel free to change if not ok. ;)